# Is the restriction of a projection map open?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a locally closed algebraic sub variety of $\mathbb C^{m+n}$. Let $p: \mathbb C^{m+n}\to \mathbb C^{m}$ be the projection map. Suppose that the restriction of $p$ to $X$ is injective. Is the map $p: X \to p(X)$ open in Euclidean topology? Note that $p(X)$ is Zariski constructible in $\mathbb C^{m}$.

Comment: What if $\tilde Y \to Y$ is the resolution of a node $y$ with preimages $p,q$, and $X = \tilde Y \setminus \{q\}$? Then $X \to Y$ is a bijection, but not a homeomorphism: a small neighbourhood of $p$ will map to a locally closed subset of $Y$ contained in only one of the sheets through $y$. (Just stick these inside affine spaces if that's what you want.)

Comment: [Crossposted from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3765939/is-this-injective-projection-map-open). In general, you should wait much longer than 43 minutes before cross-posting, and you ought to link all versions of your post together.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the example and the notice.